# android studio updater SDK manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I have installed and tried the android studio for the first time. It is looking great. But, when I try to update something from the SDK manager, I have the following problem:

```
    Downloading Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision 1
    Installing Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision 1
    Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\system-images\android-20\android-wear\armeabi-v7a
    Downloading Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 20, revision 1
    Installing Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 20, revision 1
    Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\system-images\android-20\android-wear\x86
    Downloading Android Support Library, revision 20
    Installing Android Support Library, revision 20
    Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\android\support
```

I gave the write permission to the folder. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the Android Studio in Administrator mode. That should help.

If you are using Windows, just right click on the Android Studio icon and choose "Run as Administrator"